# roslaunch ssh error

Tags: ros, roslaunch, xml, multiple, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am getting the following error when attempting to launch a series of nodes across two machines..

- beaglebone black (ubuntu@bbone):
  ubuntu 14.04 LTS  (3.14 kernel) and
  ROS indigo
- Linux workstation (thayer@T1538):
  ubuntu 14.04 LTS (3.14 kernel) and
  ROS indigo

I have verified that both machines have the correct ROS_MASTER_URI environment variables set, and I have full bi-directional internet connectivity between the two. I can get success if I start up roscore and bring up each node on the respective machines one at a time, but can't get the launch file to work. Also, FWIW, **the `sys.excepthook is missing lost sys.stderr` error message occurs often on the beaglebone after killing roscore if it is running, however has never affected functionality in any way.** Does this point to a deeper issue?

**Error message:**

```
thayer@T1538:~/catkin_ws/src/mvp_ros/launch$ roslaunch mvp_ros rangetest.launch 
... logging to /home/thayer/.ros/log/b097f6ac-dbd8-11e5-a8ba-78acc0a5686d/roslaunch-T1538-9473.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://T1538:44498/
remote[bbone-0] starting roslaunch
remote[bbone-0]: creating ssh connection to bbone:22, user[ubuntu]
launching remote roslaunch child with command: [env ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh roslaunch -c bbone-0 -u http://T1538:44498/ --run_id b097f6ac-dbd8-11e5-a8ba-78acc0a5686d]
remote[bbone-0]: ssh connection created
remote[bbone-0]: Exception while registering with roslaunch parent [http://T1538:44498/]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 506, in _register_with_server
    code, msg, _ = server.register(name, self.uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1233, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1587, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1273, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1301, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1448, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 778, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr

[bbone-0] killing on exit
remote roslaunch failed to launch: bone
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

**Launch File:**

```
<launch>
    <machine name="bone" address="bbone" default="true" user="ubuntu" password="ubuntu"/>
    <machine name="thayer" address="localhost" default="true"/>

    <node name="relay" pkg="mvp_ros" type="xbox_ser_relay" machine="bone"/>
    <node name="teleop" pkg="mvp_ros" type="teleop_xbox" machine="bone"/>
    <node name="joystick" pkg="joy" type="joy_node" machine="thayer"> 
        <param name="dev" value="/dev/input/js0"/> 
    </node>
</launch>
```

EDIT1: Has nobody ever seen this error before? It seems oddly specific. I also get it when I try to launch on my raspberry pi. I have included the log file here. The key parts are below.

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,291: started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.117:38349/
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,291: ... parent XML-RPC server started
[roslaunch.remote][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,291: remote[pi-3-0] starting roslaunch
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,292: remote[pi-3-0] starting roslaunch
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,292: remote[pi-3-0]: creating ssh connection to pi-3:22, user[pi]
[roslaunch.remoteprocess][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,292: remote[pi-3-0]: invoking with ssh exec args [/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh roslaunch -c pi-3-0 -u http://192.168.1.117:38349/ --run_id 8d8946
cc-de79-11e5-9723-b8e85632a8ba]
[paramiko.transport][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,363: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.7p1)
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,366: Exception: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367: Traceback (most recent call last):
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1585, in run
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367:     self._handler_table[ptype](self, m)
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1664, in _negotiate_keys
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367:     self._parse_kex_init(m)
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1779, in _parse_kex_init
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367:     raise SSHException('Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)')
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367: SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
[paramiko.transport][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,367: 
[roslaunch.remoteprocess][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,370: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/remoteprocess.py", line 192, in _ssh_exec
    ssh.connect(address, port, username, password, timeout=TIMEOUT_SSH_CONNECT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 306, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 465, in start_client
    raise e
SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)

[roslaunch][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,370: remote[pi-3-0]: failed to launch on mvp:

Unable to establish ssh connection to [pi@pi-3:22]: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)

[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,371: ProcessMonitor.register[pi-3-0]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,371: ProcessMonitor.register[pi-3-0] complete
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,371: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 140521618212608)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,379: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 140521618212608)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,379: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 140521618212608)>: remaining procs are [<roslaunch.remoteprocess.SSHChildROSLaunchProcess object at 0x7fcdbd4ef3d0>]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,380: ProcessMonitor exit: killing pi-3-0
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,380: [pi-3-0] killing on exit
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,381: ProcessMonitor exit: cleaning up data structures and signals
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,381: ProcessMonitor exit: pmon has shutdown
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,381: unable to start remote roslaunch child: pi-3-0
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,381: The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,381: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 230, in _start_infrastructure
    self._start_remote()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 210, in _start_remote
    self.remote_runner.start_children()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/remote.py", line 124, in start_children
    p = self._start_child(server_node_uri, machines[m], counter)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/remote.py", line 97, in _start_child
    raise RLException("unable to start remote roslaunch child: %s"%name)
RLException: unable to start remote roslaunch child: pi-3-0

[rospy.core][INFO] 2016-02-28 19:15:35,381: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

Thanks,

Brett

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227577/roslaunch-ssh-error/) by [bigbrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/25990/bigbrett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the solution after much digging....

The error lay in the version of paramiko on my computer, as seen [here](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/423). I updated paramiko and then that error went away. I also needed to provide an env-loader option in my .launch file when I declared the remote machine. Once I did this, everything worked.

I don't have enough points to accept my own answer, but if someone else could flag it as accepted, that would be great.

---

Originally posted by [bigbrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/25990/bigbrett/) with karma: 58 on 2016-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2